# Parse cloud code - how to edit code?

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to the Parse cloud code command line tool...(and I understand Parse is going away...I am coming onto an existing project). I've downloaded the pares command line tool, and  now I'm literally just trying to find the code and open it in an editor. When I use

```
parse list
These are the apps you currently have access to:
1:  YourApp
2:  Project1
```

I want to get to some cron jobs that are running in  YourApp. I have actually read over the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line)...Maybe I'm missing it but where is a simple example of opening the docs, editing them, and testing them etc? I know JavaScript so how can I get to the file so I can write some JavaScript? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Steve. You can just navigate in the folders to see your files. They will be located in your YourApp/cloud/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parse new` and follow the prompts to clone your app on your computer.

Then you can edit whatever you want and then use `parse deploy` to update.

Documentation: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line

Comment: I have already done parse new. I have my projects on my computer. My entire question is what you gloss over. How do I EDIT?